# Exec-wrapper.sh: does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, wrapper

I'm currently using lambda function which is invoked using Aws Lex. It was working normally and I didn't modify any of its configuration and out of nowhere it stopped working and I keep getting this error.

> /opt/sls-sdk-node/exec-wrapper.sh: does not exist

Can anyone please explain what is an exec-wrapper.sh and how is it possible for it to suddenly disappear? And how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that after removing the serverless framework, there were some configurations (exec-wrapper.sh) that were not removed and needed to be removed manually from lambda using the aws console

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an error stemming from the Serverless framework rather than an issue with Lex itself. Did you perhaps upgrade any of the SLS dependencies?